# API TRELLO JQuery Cannot Call "Lists" data after press the button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, trello

i'm new to API Trello, right now i'm trying to make a button, and what the button does was, get a "lists" in each board. unfortunately when i'm trying to make the button works to call the data first, the message show [object object] can you guys help me?

PS : 
1. i know that Take Lists by button already exist and i already read it..   2. [object object] already exist too and i already read it too, but in the end, mine still didn't work.
3. please don't forget to change [your-key] to your own key that you find on trello

thank you guys, any responds will be appreciated.

here is my script HTML & JQuery

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Dashboard Prototype</h1>

     <select id="boards"></select>
    <!-- <select id="lists"></select>-->
     <div id="labels"></div>
     <button id="btn1">Click to View Lists</button>
     <p id="p">a</p>
     <!--<div id="lists"></div>-->

</body>
```

```
<!--GET&SET BOARDS-->
    var loadedBoards = function(boards) {
        $.each(boards, function(index, value) {
            $('#boards')
            .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",value.id)
                .text(value.name)
            ); 
        });
    };
    var loadBoards = function() {
        Trello.get(
            '/members/me/boards/',
            loadedBoards,
            function() { console.log("Failed to load boards"); }
        );
    };

<!--SET TO LABELS-->    
    var loadedLabels = function(labels) {
        $.each(labels, function(index, label) {
            var label = $("<p><span class='badge' style='background:" + label.color + ";'>" + label.uses + "</span> " + label.idBoard +"</p>");
            $('#labels').append(label)
        });
    };
    $('#boards').change(function() {
        var boardId = $("option:selected", this).val();
        $('#labels').empty();

        Trello.get(
            '/boards/' + boardId + '/labels',
            loadedLabels,
            function() { console.log("Failed to load labels"); }
        );
    });

<!--SET TO LISTS--> 

    var loadedLists = function(list) {
        $.each(lists, function(index, list) {
            var list = $("<p>" + lists.idLists + lists.name + "</p>");
            $('#lists').append(list)

        });
    };

    var tarikL = $(function(){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $('#boards').change(function() {
                var boardId = $("option:selected", this).val();
                $('#lists').empty();

                Trello.get(
                    '/boards/' + boardId + '/lists',
                    loadedLists,
                    function() { console.log("Failed to load lists"); }
                );
            })
            $("#p").text($("#btn1"));
        });
    });



<!--POP UP AUTHORIZATION TRELLO-->
    Trello.authorize({
        type: "popup",
        name: "Trello dashboard",
        scope: {
            read: true,
            write: false 
        },
        expiration: "never",
        success: loadBoards,
        error: function() { console.log("Failed authentication"); }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I didn't get all the way into the code, but a button press has got nothing to do with a failing RESTful request to an API. You might want to test the request to the endpoint with a tool like Postmen and ones you got that working integrate with your front-end code. Same goes for the UI, first make it work then integrate. Good luck!